# setparameter and like

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'd like to use NHibernates setparameter-feature, but I don't know how to achieve something like `where Lastname like '%xyz%'` (please notice the two %):

```
string hql = "... where Lastname like :Lastname";
// ...
hibQuery.SetParameter("Lastname", myValue);
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't result in an unsharp search. Either I write the lastname correctly, or nothing is found: 'Smi' -> Smith is not found.

How am I supposed to correct that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do either

```
hql = "... where Lastname like :Lastname";
query.SetParameter("Lastname", '%' + myValue + '%');
```

or

```
hql = "... where Lastname like concat('%', :Lastname, '%')";
query.SetParameter("Lastname", myValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hibQuery.SetParameter("Lastname", "%"+myValue+"%");
```